Styling is corrupted in an EXE output from building with pyinstaller
I have a python project based on PyQt5 which I build the GUI using PyQt5 Designer. The python file when it is run, there is no issue found.
I build it with pyinstaller using the below command:
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --add-data "background.png;." --add-data "icon.png;." --icon=icon.ico myproject.py

The output resulted in dist folder but the icon not loaded and the background too.
I tried pyinstaller, cx-freeze, Nuitka and py2exe and no one worked well.

Would be more accurately described as "data files not included" than "styling corrupted", no? Anyhow -- how is PyQt5 Designer configured to find those files? Make sure you're including a [MRE] with the shortest possible set of all the steps and details that create a situation where the same thing happens when followed without changes.

The bundles created for "frozen" binaries extract the content in a temporary path which is not the cwd, you need to always dynamically rebuild that if you need access to local resources. Alternatively, use the Qt resource system along with the pyrcc utility (which is not available anymore in PyQt6, but alternatives exist).
